# Xamarin.Android application doesn't start the second time

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I've created a simple application with Xamarin trial edition, which just shows a splash screen. After I hit "Run" in Xamarin studio it deploys and runs just fine, but if I click "Home" on the device and try to run application from the application list - screen flickers for a moment and application gets terminated, no breakpoints get hit on the second run. This is true for both emulator and a physical device.

I doubt it matters, but my code is as following.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using System;
using Android.Views;

namespace MyApplication.Activities
{
    [Activity(Label = "My application", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Splash);
        }
    }
}
```

Does the problem occur because it's a trial edition of Xamarin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like trial edition is indeed causing my problems. Adb logcat had lines:

```
I/ActivityManager(  308): Displayed MyApplication/MyApplication.Activities.SplashActivity: +845ms
D/Finsky  (  759): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
I/ActivityManager(  308): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.int
ent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=MyApplication/MyApplication.TrialSplashS
creenf2b499ae00e24b5ba2aa0253572b8e1e u=0} from pid 518
D/dalvikvm(  308): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1293K, 15% free 18885K/22023K, paused 66ms
, total 67ms
D/dalvikvm( 7162): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/ActivityManager(  308): Start proc MyApplication for activity MyApplication/MyApplication.TrialSplashScreenf2b499ae00e24b5ba2aa0253572b8e1e: pid=7162 uid=10067 g
ids={3003, 1015, 1028}
I/dalvikvm( 7162): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 10.
..
I/ActivityThread( 7162): Pub MyApplication.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__
: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
D/dalvikvm( 7162): Trying to load lib /data/data/MyApplication/lib/libmonodroid.s
o 0x4266ae60
D/dalvikvm( 7162): Added shared lib /data/data/MyApplication/lib/libmonodroid.so
0x4266ae60
F/MonoDroid( 7162): **This installation has expired**.
D/Zygote  (  125): Process 7162 exited cleanly (11)
```

Although, trial splash screen states, that build will work for 24 hours - it expires immediately for some reason. Oh well, I can live with that.

Update:
Yep, problem went away after I purchased and activated a license.